# Sort vector of elements or pointers to elements

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a single function that can sort a `vector<MyType>` or a `vector<MyType*>`?

I have the existing bit of code

```
template <class Iterator>
void SortMyType(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
  std::sort(first, last, [](const MyType& a, const MyType& b) {
      return a.some_value() < b.some_value();
    });
}
```

which works great when I have `std::vector<MyType>`. But now I want to sort a `std::vector<MyType*>` and I want to use the exact same logic. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: What's the problem?  Change `a` and `b` to be pointers and then use `->`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I'm trying to avoid duplicating the code since the `*` and `->` would be the only difference.

Comment: your function does nothing else than calling a algorithm, hence I would not call it code duplication to call the algorithm for different type of parameters, though the answer convinced me of the contrary ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 the function has been pared down to get at the crux of the problem. In practice it does other things as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-use most of that function if you abstract away the "get the value" part.

```
template <class Iterator>
void SortMyType(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
  using ObjeceType = decltype(*first);
  std::sort(first, last, [](const ObjectType& a, const ObjectType& b) {
      return getValue(a) < getValue(b);
    });
}
```

Where

```
ReturnType getValue(MyType const& o)
{
   return o.some_value;
}

ReturnType getValue(MyType const* p)
{
    return getValue(*p);
}
```

Comment: You need to make `a` and `b` generic.  Otherwise I like this.

Comment: Oh this is pretty elegant.